# SMSCASTER Sms sending Script PHP

Tags: sms

I'm using SMSCASTER software to send sms through laptop. But Now I want to get php code that I use to send sms through website. Any help? I have licensed SMSCASTER software.

Comment: Please provide some sample code that you have already tried.

Comment: @Ankit I don't know about this.. I know PHP.. but don't know how to connect it with software. I just using software to send sms.